# INTEGRAL OF INVERSE FUNCTION using $g(2x)=2f(x)$

Tags: integration, inverse

[image]

Before proceeding I looked at the concept which is illustrated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions

I approached as $g\left( x \right) = {f^{ - 1}}\left( x \right)$

$g\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = {f^{ - 1}}\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = x$

$g\left( {f\left( x \right)} \right) = {f^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{{g\left( {2x} \right)}}{2}} \right) = x$

$\int\limits_1^8 {xf'\left( x \right)dx}  = \frac{q}{p}$

$\left[ {x\int {f'\left( x \right)dx} } \right]_1^8 - \int\limits_1^8 {\frac{d}{{dx}}x\left( {\int {f'\left( x \right)dx} } \right)dx}  = \frac{q}{p} \Rightarrow \left[ {xf\left( x \right)} \right]_1^8 - \int\limits_1^8 {f\left( x \right)dx}  = \frac{q}{p}$

$ \Rightarrow \left[ {8f\left( 8 \right) - f\left( 1 \right)} \right] - \int\limits_1^8 {f\left( x \right)dx}  = \frac{q}{p}$

Not able to procced as not able to use the substitution $g(2x)=2f(x)$

Comment: How do we calcukate $f(8)$, we know that $f(1)=1$

Comment: Answer is $\frac{139}{4}$, then $p+q=143$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $g(2x)=2f(x)$ and $f(1)=1,$ one easily derives $f(2^n)=2^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ (by induction), so (according to your calculations)
$$\frac qp=63-\int_1^8f(x)dx.$$

Thanks to the link you provided,
$$\int_2^4f(x)dx=4^2-2^2-\int_2^4g(x)dx$$
$$=12-2\int_1^2g(2t)dt=12-4\int_1^2f(t)dt=12-5=7,$$
and similarly,
$$\int_4^8f(x)dx=8^2-4^2-4\int_2^4f(t)dt=48-28=20,$$
and we can conclude:
$$\frac qp=63-\frac54-7-20=\frac{139}4$$
and $p+q=139+4=143.$

Comment: What is the role of $\int_1^2f(x)dx=\frac{5}{4}$ in your solution

Comment: It is use twice: in $12-4\int_1^2f(t)dt=12-5$ and in $\frac qp=63-\frac54-7-20.$

Comment: Thanking you for the prompt reply